# How to pass a variable from Shiny app to R Markdown?

Tags: r, shiny

In my toy example, I am trying to render Rmd file in the shiny app while passing a variable from Shiny to Rmd. Somehow, the Rmd file is not able to pick the input `input$selectInput` passed to Rmd file. Can someone show me how to pass a variable from Shiny to Rmd file and print it there?

My intent is to use Rmd file as a template which will be filled by variables from Shiny App at runtime. There may be better alternatives to this approach to render HTML templates in Shiny, do let me know if you know any better approches.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(knitr)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  collapsed = FALSE,
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "menu_sidebar",
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 1'",
      selectizeInput(inputId = "selectInput", label = "Choose an option", choices = c("a", "b", "c"), selected = "a", multiple = FALSE),
      radioButtons(inputId = "buttons", label = "Choose one:",
                   choices=c(
                     "A" = "a",
                     "B" = "b"))
    )
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "main_tab",
      selected = "tab 1",
      tabPanel(title = "tab 1", "Tab content 1", 
               conditionalPanel("input.buttons == 'a'", 
                                {
                                  knit("text1.Rmd", envir = globalenv(), quiet = T)
                                  withMathJax(includeMarkdown("text1.md"))
                                },
                                tags$style("html, body {overflow: visible !important;")),
               conditionalPanel("input.buttons == 'b'", htmlOutput("plot_overview_handler"))
      )
    )
  )
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    sidebar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tabset1Selected <- output$tabset2Selected <- renderText({
      input$main_tab
    })
    output$plot_overview_handler <- renderUI({
      pars <- list(variable_1 = input$selectInput)
      includeMarkdown(rmarkdown::render(input = "text2.Rmd", 
                                        output_format = "html_document",
                                        params = pars,
                                        run_pandoc = FALSE,
                                        quiet = TRUE,
                                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())))
    })
  }
)
```

**Rmd File 1 - text1.Rmd**

````
---
title: "tst2"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
#``` # Uncomment this to run code

## R Markdown

```{r cars}
print(input$selectInput)
#``` # Uncomment this to run code
````

**Rmd File 2 - text2.Rmd**

````
---
title: "tst2"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
params:
  variable_1: NA
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
#``` # Uncomment this to run code

## R Markdown

```{r cars}
print(params$variable_1)
#``` # Uncomment this to run code
````

[image]

Comment: Are you calling `rmarkdown::render` from your shiny app? Regardless, in general the way to pass data to an rmarkdown document is to use [parameterized reports](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html).

Comment: I have added second option in app to include code for ```rmarkdown::render```. Somehow I am getting issues rendering with it too.

Comment: Your edits (to add `params`) look good, not sure what else is happening.

Comment: Possibly that first print statement is error'ing out the rmd file? I normally set my params to NA in rmd. ie. `variable_1: NA` Not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: With rmarkdown::render, I am getting error ```object 'input' not found```. Changing to ```variable_1: NA``` does not resolved the issue.

Comment: That's because `input` doesn't exist in the rmd env. You've set `input$selectInput` to `params$variable_1`.  In the rmd - reference your params.

Comment: The second Rmd file is now working fine. Thanks, @Jamie. Do you have any suggestions for the first Rmd file? Running first Rmd file, I am getting error ```Error in print(input$selectInput): object 'input' not found```. Is there a way to pass variable from Shiny to Rmd file using ```knit("text1.Rmd", envir = globalenv(), quiet = T)```?

Comment: I don't have any experience using that method. I would advise using rmarkdown::render like you've done for the second rmd file!